# Should I use ContractPromise as a substitute of Promise for a NEAR nft-implementation in AssemblyScript?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to create my own NFT implementation in NEAR, using `near-sdk-as` in AssemblyScript. I'm following the [Non-Fungible Token (NEP-171)](https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Core.html#nft-interface) protocol specification (Version 1.0.1), and one of the functions have this signature, which returns a `Promise`

```ts
function nft_transfer_call(
  receiver_id: string,
  token_id: string,
  approval_id: number|null,
  memo: string|null,
  msg: string,
): Promise {}
```

Currently, as far as I know, [AssemblyScript doesn't implement a Promise](https://www.assemblyscript.org/status.html#promises), so I'm wondering if I should use `ContractPromise` from `near-sdk-as` instead?

I'm planning to "panic" in the function, so maybe the return type doesn't matter, but the question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right, you're talking about contract promises for cross-contract calls on NEAR

You can learn more about cross-contract calls here: https://github.com/near-examples/cross-contract-calls

Keep in mind that, although `near-sdk-rs` and `near-sdk-as` both use the word "Promise", this is NOT the same thing as a promise in JavaScript.